# Android studio how to delete messages in chat properly

Tags: android-studio

I'm facing an issue with deleting messages in my chat app. I have two types of messages, image and text. and I delete them like this:

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        Query query = dbRef.orderByChild("time").equalTo(msgTimeStamp);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    if (ds.child("sender").getValue().equals(myUID) && !ds.child("message").getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("This message was deleted")) {
                        holder.messageLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                                View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custon_view_for_dialog,  null);
                                builder.setView(view);
                                Button delete = view.findViewById(R.id.delete);
                                Button cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                                final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

                                delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        deleteMessage(position);
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });

                                dialog.show();

                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
 
   @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
```

And here is the delete function:

```
 private void deleteMessage(int position) {
 String msgTimeStamp = mChats.get(position).getTime();
    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    Query query = dbRef.orderByChild("time").equalTo(msgTimeStamp);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (final DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren())
            {

                if(ds.child("type").getValue().equals("text"))
                {
                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("message", "This message was deleted");
                    ds.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
                }
                else
                {
                    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                    StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(ds.child("message").getValue().toString());
                    storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("message", "This message was deleted");
                            hashMap.put("type","text");
                            ds.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

so my idea here is if the message is text, then I set the text as "This message was deleted" and if the message is an image, I change its type to text and set it also to "This message was deleted" and delete the image from Firebase Storage. The deleting works for me and here is how it looks like after deleting:

[image]

The issue I'm facing is that I can still delete the message even if it is already deleted!!
I don't want the `AlertDialog` for deleting to appear when I click on a deleted message !!.

as you can see I added this to my condition :

```
!ds.child("message").getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("This message was deleted")
```

but the issue is still there, deleted messages can be deleted more than once! how can I prevent this from happening? please help

Comment: You need to remove the onLongClickListener when the message is deleted. BTW, what happens when a user sends "This message was deleted" as the message?

Comment: how to remove onLongClickListener. Well "This message was deleted" is unacceptable message so it won't allow the user to send it.  I already handled this.

Comment: try `setOnLongClickListener(null)`.

Comment: where exactly I should add this? at the end of  deleteMessage() function?

Comment: seems to work, can you please add your solution as an answer instead of a comment? so I can accept it.